# How to call and pack widget class frames into a main window application class? tkinter

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I'm having trouble creating a database GUI. 
I am creating the widgets as class ***(tk.Frame):
I then try and create and pack them in a "MainApplication(tk.Frame): class.
However, the widgets do not appear.
I am a little confused about the root, and "self" that I am passing into the MainApplication and then from there into the widget classes. 
How do I get the widgets showing up?

```
'''
Created on 26/11/2013

@author: User
'''
# ============== Import ==========================================#
import Tkinter as tk
import MySQLdb
import tkFont
''' '''  
# ============== Functions & Helpers =========================== #
def new_customer_window():
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.title("new customer box")

    e1 = tk.Entry(top)
    e2 = tk.Entry(top)

    e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

def launchNext():
    pass

def updateRecordStatus(table, rowID, newstatus):
    top = tk.Toplevel()
    top.title("Update called")
    cmd = "UPDATE jobs SET STATUS=%s WHERE ID=%s"  # CHANGE jobs to VARIABLE!!
    print(table, rowID, newstatus)
    db = MySQLdb.connect ("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "popupbikes")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(cmd, (newstatus, rowID))
    db.close()

def editRecord(table, rowID):
    pass

class data:
    def __init__(self, dataName):
        db = MySQLdb.connect ("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "popupbikes")
        self.cursor = db.cursor()
        self.dataName = dataName
        self.cursor = db.cursor()
        s = "Select * from %s" % dataName
        self.cursor.execute(s)
        dataAll = self.cursor.fetchall()
        db.close()
    def row_count(self):    
        self.numrows = self.cursor.rowcount()
        return self.numrows

    def fields(self):
        self.fields = len(self.cursor.description())
        return self.fields
''' '''  
# ============== GUI Classes ===========================#
class JobTab(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, windowName, WIDTH, HEIGHT):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master


# THIS IS THE WIDGET I AM TRYING TO DRAW ON THE MAIN WINDOW AS A TEST
class ActionButtons(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master

        self.TitleFont = tkFont.Font(family="Harlow Solid Italic", size=30)

        # Create Buttons
        self.actionButtonContainer = tk.Frame(self.master)  # Frame for set
        self.newJobButton = tk.Button(self.actionButtonContainer,
                                      text="New Job",
                                      command=new_customer_window,
                                      font=self.TitleFont)
        self.editCustomerButton = tk.Button(self.actionButtonContainer,
                                            text="Edit Customer Details",
                                            command=new_customer_window,
                                            font=self.TitleFont)
        # Pack Frame
        self.newJobButton.pack(expand=1, padx=40, pady=20)
        self.editCustomerButton.pack(expand=1, padx=40, pady=20)
        print("Buttons Packed??")

class DataWidget(tk.Frame):
    # Rowbuttons specified as a list with [[label, command function]i]
    def __init__(self, master, datatype, fields, rows, rowbuttons):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.dataype = datatype
        self.fields = fields
        self.rows = rows
        self.rowbuttons = rowbuttons
        self.container = 1
''' '''     
# ============== Build GUI in root ===========================#
class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, windowName, WIDTH, HEIGHT):
        # Root window set-up
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.TitleFont = tkFont.Font(family="Harlow Solid Italic", size=30)
        self.master = master # Self assign root for passing into other classes        
        self.master.title(windowName)   # Title
        w, h = master.winfo_screenwidth()-15, master.winfo_screenheight()-65
        master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h))   # Root Window Geometry
        # Create widget objects
        self.labelTitle = tk.Label(master, text=windowName, 
                                   font=self.TitleFont, bg="white", width =55)
        self.actionbuttons = ActionButtons(self)  # THIS IS MAYBE WHERE IT IS
                                                  # GOING WRONG!?
        # Pack everything into the root window!
        self.labelTitle.pack()  # THIS PACKS PROPERLY
        self.actionbuttons.pack()   # THIS DOESN"T APPEAR
''' '''     
# ============== Initialize Program ===========================#
def main(): 
    root = tk.Tk()
    # Set fonts 
    SubTitleFont = tkFont.Font(family="Cambria", size=13)
    HeaderFont = tkFont.Font(family="Cambria", size=10, weight="bold") 
    TextFont = tkFont.Font(family="Cambria", size=10)

    # Initialize Root Window
    SCREEN_WIDTH = root.winfo_screenwidth() - 30
    SCREEN_HEIGHT = root.winfo_screenheight() - 100
    PopUpApp = MainApplication(root, "Pop-Up Bikes Home",
                               SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    PopUpApp.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Any other tips would also be appreciated!

Comment: Hello Peter! Welcome to SO. As a general recommendation: try to avoid general and open ended questions. You won't get a real answer or no answer at all. Keep it concise, practical and up to a point - a *single* point - garner it with some example, and tracebacks. That way your answer may get in as fast as in 5 Minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a frame named `actionButtonContainer`, and putting buttons in it. However, you never use pack or grid to make this frame visible, so it and all of its children will be invisible.

Since ActionButtons is already a frame, I don't see why you need this container frame. You probably just want to make the buttons children of `self`.

Comment: Ah, Brian Oakley to the rescue again! You solved it! I'm basically learning python by your posts. Thanks so much!